# Use Google NDB to connect to cloud storage

Tags: python, google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb, webapp2

I maintain older app using Python, webapp2 and ndb. When running the app locally from PyCharm, dev_appserver uses local version of datastore but I'd like to use cloud datastore. Is this possible? In the end, when I run the app locally, it should access datastore of deployed app instead of local one.

[This tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/datastore/docs/datastore-api-tutorial) shows the solution but it is using `datastore` from `google.cloud` while my app uses `ndb` from `google.appengine.ext`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to access cloud storage from outside of GAE (locally) you need to switch to the datastore API.

See this thread: [what's the difference between google.appengine.ext.ndb and gcloud.datastore?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39441764/whats-the-difference-between-google-appengine-ext-ndb-and-gcloud-datastore)

Comment: That's not really an option as it would require a rewrite of certain parts of application. Well, that's a bummer :( thanks for the link!

Comment: To bad - you could also have a look at this post to get the fuller picture https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40872410/client-library-for-cloud-datastore-on-app-engine-ndb-or-google-cloud-datastore